# How do I use javascript for html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner of Javascript and html. I want to output 10 "Hi" but following code doesn't work. What should I do?

index.html and app.js is in a same folder.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var main = function(){
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    var f = document.createElement('p');
    f.innerText = "Hi.";
    var div = document.getElementByClass('test');
    div.appendChild(f);
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: don't use innerText, use textContent or.text() unless you really want the extra innerText whitespace and you only care about CH+IE

Comment: you should not add thanks in your question but mark as solution the answer you choose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Look in your browser's JavaScript error console
2. See the error about `$` being undefined and thus a reference error
3. Define `$` (which you probably want to do by including [the jQuery library](http://jquery.com/))

Alternatively, just get rid of `$(document).ready(main);` and call `main()` directly instead. You don't appear to have any need for jQuery in there.

You'll then have to contend with `getElementByClass` not being a function. See [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) instead.

Comment: One more, need to add `JQ` library before `app.js`

Comment: @Bharadwaj — See point three, and the paragraph following it.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you are referencing [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) without including it

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

add the link to jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

then your script has some errors:

**try to use the developer console of your browser to debug it**

your code should look like this:

```
var main = function(){
    /*no need to exec this for all loops iteration
    and the right method is getElementByClassName not getElementByClass */
    var div = document.getElementByClassName('test')[0];

    for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
        var f = document.createElement('p');
        f.innerText = "Hi.";    
        div.appendChild(f);
    };
} /*you forgot to close the function*/
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var f = document.createElement('p'),
          div = document.querySelector('.test');

      f.innerText = 'Hi';
      div.appendChild(f);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. You need to include the jQuery library
2. Your function is missing a closing `}`
3. It's `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementByClass`
4. If it's just going to be one div, why not use ID instead? Like so:

> ```
> $(function () {
>     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>         var f = document.createElement('p');
>         f.innerText = "Hi.";
>         var div = document.getElementById('test');
>         div.appendChild(f);
>     }
> });
> ```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phgwbpsx/)